# Sending TestFlight invitation mail to External users in different Language

Tags: ios, app-store, app-store-connect, testflight

I uploaded the Binary for External users Testing and added the localized description for build in English and Japanese.

However, to my Japanese external users i want to send the invitation mail in Japanese. I changed the Browser language, primary language from App Information to Japanese; but invitation mail is always sent in English language.

Could anyone please let me know the other settings where i can send the mail in other then English?

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunately there's currently no way to localize/translate the TestFlight email itself. Only the metadata within the TestFlight app for your own app will be shown in the user's language.

I suggest filling a bug report over at https://bugreport.apple.com as I agree the email should get automatically translated.

Comment: Is it always sent in English or could I get it sent in another language if I changed the language in my own user account?

Comment: It's always sent in English, unfortunately you have no influence on the language of the emails.