# TestFlight: localize the invitation email?

Tags: ios, iphone, ipad, app-store-connect, testflight

Some of my testers have problems with English, it's possibile to translate or customize the invitation email?

Comment: No, similar question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36418279/sending-testflight-invitation-mail-to-external-users-in-different-language